# How to best clean up a SQLDataReader when using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqldatareader

I have a method that returns a data reader.  Normally I would wrap a using around the data reader so that it gets disposed nicely after I iterate through it.  THe problem is that I've chosen to consume the data reader using Linq, which means that the defered execution causes the reader to get disposed early.  Is there a proper pattern to consume and dispose of the data reader using Linq without having to built a complete collection of it's contents?

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = CallStoredProcedure())
{
    return reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>().Select(rec => new ObjectModel.CollectorSummaryItem()
    {
        CollectorID = (int)rec[0],
        Name = rec.IsDBNull(1) ? null : rec.GetString(1),
        Information = rec.IsDBNull(2) ? null : rec.GetString(2)
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply delegating the read? Create a method that accepts IDataRecord and builds your object. Build a list off of it and return that list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to actually read from the reader inside the using block:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = CallStoredProcedure())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return new ObjectModel.CollectorSummaryItem()
        {
            CollectorID = (int)reader[0],
            Name = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(1),
            Information = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : reader.GetString(2)
        };
    }
}
```

This will evaluate to code with the same or consistent return type with what you had before, but doesn't close the reader until *after* you're done reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip here. This should help you decouple the reader logic as well.

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> ExecuteNonQuery(...)
{
  ...
  using(var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
  {
    var results = new List<MyObject>();
    return reader
            .Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>()
            .Select(rec => GetFromReader(rec))
            .ToList();
  }
}

public MyObject GetFromReader(IDataRecord rdr)
{
   return new MyObject { Prop1 = rdr["prop1"], Prop2 = rdr["prop2"] };
}
```

Comment: There is a slight problem with that code. LINQ is lazy and won't evaluate the lambda expression until you enumerate over the `IEnumerable`, which will likely be outside of the method given. By that time, the `using` statement would have disposed of `reader`. If you used a method like `ToList()` after the `Select` statement to force the enumeration of the `IEnumerable` inside the `using` block, that might work.