# Convert the reader to the list of class

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a class

```
Class Student
{
    Int studentId,
    List<ClassB> Books 
}

Class Book
{
    Int  bookId,
    List<int> pages
}
```

My stored proc will return something like this

```
StudentId         bookId.      Page
1                         101.            500
1.                        102.            600
2.                        101.            400,500
2                         103.            500,600,700
```

I would like to represent this as student Class

I am able to group by the studentID but not able to get books
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        var res = GetStudents();
        var result = res.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.StudentId,r.IsPassed })
    .Select(c =>
            new Student()
            {
                IsPassed = c.Key.IsPassed,
                StudentId = c.Key.StudentId,

            }).ToList();



    }

private static List<Student> GetStudents()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"];
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Students", conn);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["StudentId"]);
            var BookId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["BookId"]);
            var IsPassed = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsPassed"]);
            var PageNUmbers = reader["PageNumber"].ToString().Split(',').Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t)).ToList();
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
            books.Add(new Book() { BookId = BookId, PageNumber = PageNUmbers });
            students.Add(new Student() { StudentId = StudentId, Books = books, IsPassed = IsPassed });
        }
    }
    return students;

}
```

Comment: use `while(reader.read()){ // code to map }`

Comment: "I have a class" - looks like 2 classes to me; are you trying to merge the data into one list?

Comment: @tim yeah sorry my bad

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

page is not a collection, it is just an integer. Each student has a list of books each book has an Id and a page number property.

```
Class Student
{
Int studentId,
List<Book> Books 
}

Class Book
{
Int  bookId,
Int numberOfPages
}
```

Comment: I want to consider the page numbers too.

Comment: what is the number of pages in your Book class?

Comment: My book class don't have number of pages it has Page numbers

Comment: both are the same because both are considered as one integer that define the number of pages. as book1 is 300 pages. book2 is 250.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of `Linq`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("StudentId"))
    .Select(c=> 
            new Student() 
            {
                studentId = c.Key, 
                Books = c.GroupBy(s=>s.Field<int>("bookId"))
                    .Select(b=> 
                            new Book() 
                            {
                                bookId = b.Key, 
                                pages = b.Select(s=>s.Field<int>("Page")).ToList() 
                            }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XIlxyN)

**Update :**

Since the question is updated to say pages received in `,` separated form, you can modify the query to

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("StudentId"))
            .Select(c=> 
                    new Student() 
                    {
                        studentId = c.Key, 
                        Books = c.GroupBy(s=>s.Field<int>("bookId"))
                            .Select(b=> 
                                    new Book() 
                                    {
                                        bookId = b.Key, 
                                        pages = b.SelectMany(p=>p.Field<string>("Page").Split(',').Select(int.Parse)).ToList() 
                                    }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Please note, you can even simplify this answer if you say `studentId, bookId` combination is unique.

Updated [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3T6cmq)

Comment: Hey i just modified my question can you let me know how it should be. The page numbers will be separated by comma

Comment: So pages is a not a `List<int>`?

Comment: It is a list but from database i will get comma separeted.

Comment: Hey can we do this without using DataTable. Just by assigning the variables first from reader and grouping ?

Comment: It is possible, take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179996/how-to-best-clean-up-a-sqldatareader-when-using-linq)

Comment: Also mark this as answer if it is solution to the question and works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103296/discussion-between-silly-volley-and-hari-prasad).